# Ruby Regex: efficient way of capturing and deleting simultaneously

Tags: ruby, regex

I am deleting comments from a code file using regular expressions in ruby. The code is C++ (but i think this is not relevant) and the file contains something like:

```
/*
    Hello! I'm a comment!
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to **remove** the comments from the code and, at the same time, to **parse** them, which for now I can achieve by doing capture and then deleting:

```
text.scan(UGLY_COMMENTS_REGEX).each do |m|
 m.method_for_printing_matched_comment
end 
text = text.gsub(UGLY_COMMENTS_REGEX,'');
```

Another alternative that occurs to me is doing the `gsub` for each regex match instead of doing it with the full regex, something like:

```
text.scan(UGLY_COMMENTS_REGEX).each do |m|
 m.method_for_printing_matched_comment
 text = text.gsub(m,'');
end
```

The problem with this (also suboptimal) alternative is that it is not straightforward when the match contains "groups", e.g m[0], m[1]...

As doing this seems extremely inefficient I was wondering if there is any way of doing the match just once (for both capturing and deleting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#gsub!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) (and other `String#gsub`, `String#sub!`, `String#sub`) accepts an optional block (which will be called with a matched string). So you can do something like this:

```
text.gsub!(UGLY_COMMENTS_REGEX) { |m|
  puts m # to print the matched comment  / OR  m.method_for_printing_matched_comment
  ''     # Return value is used as a replacement string; effectively remove the comment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work.

**Code**

```
def strip_comments(str)
  comments = []
  [str.split(/[ \t]*\/\*|\*\/(?:[ \t]*\n?/)
      .select.with_index {|ar,i| i.even? ? true : (comments << ar.strip; false)}
      .join,
   comments]
end
```

**Example**

```
str =<<_
/*
    Hello! I'm a comment!
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    /* Let's get this one too */
    foo.bar();
    return 0;
}
_

cleaned_code, comments = strip_comments(str)
puts cleaned_code
  # int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  # {
  #    Foo foo;
  #    foo.bar();
  #    return 0;
  # }

puts comments
  # Hello! I'm a comment!
  # Let's get this one too
```

**Explanation**

For the example above.

```
comments = []
```

Splitting the string on `/*` or `*/` will create an array in which every other element is the text of a comment. The first element of the array will be text to retain, which will equal `""` if the string begins with a comment. To retain correct formatting (I hope), I'm also stripping any spaces or tabs (but not newlines) that precede `/*` and any tabs or spaces followed by a newline, following `*/`.

```
b = str.split(/[ \t]*\/\*|\*\/(?:[ \t]*\n)?/)
  #=> ["",
  #    "\n    Hello! I'm a comment!\n",
  #    "\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n",
  #    " Let's get this one too ",
  #    "    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n"]
```

We wish to select the elements that are not comments, and at the same time keep the latter:

```
enum0 = b.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     "",
  #     "\n    Hello! I'm a comment!\n",
  #     "\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n",
  #     " Let's get this one too ",
  #     "    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n"]:select>
```

Add the index so we'll be able to figure out which elements are comments:

```
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [
  #     "",
  #     "\n    Hello! I'm a comment!\n",
  #     "\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n",
  #     " Let's get this one too ",
  #     "    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n"]:select>:with_index>
```

You might think of `enum1` as a "compound enumerator". To see what elements it will pass into its block, convert it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["", 0],
  #    ["\n    Hello! I'm a comment!\n", 1],
  #    ["\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n", 2],
  #    [" Let's get this one too ", 3],
  #    ["    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n", 4]]
```

Execute the enumerator with its block using `Array#each`:

```
c = enum1.each {|ar,i| i.even? ? true : (comments << ar.strip; false)}
  #=> ["",
  #    "\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n",
  #    "    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n"]
```

Confirm `comments` was constructed correctly:

```
puts comments
  # Hello! I'm a comment!
  # Let's get this one too
```

Join the elements of `c`:

```
cleaned_text = c.join
  #=> "\nint main(int argc, char* argv[])\n{\n    Foo foo;\n    foo.bar();\n    return 0;\n}\n"
```

and return:

```
[cleaned_text, comments]
```

as shown above.

**Edit: a little better, I think:**

```
def strip_comments(str)
  a = str.split(/[ \t]*\/\*|\*\/(?:[ \t]*\n)?/)
  a << "" if a.size.odd?
  cleaned, comments = a.each_pair.transpose
  [cleaned.join, comments.map(&:strip)]
end
```